# renaming uploaded files in multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

Here I'm trying to rename both the files as **file1** and **file2**, but both the files are renamed as **file2**.

#### HTML

```
<input type="file" name="file1" file-model = "file1"/>
<input type="file" name="file2" file-model = "file2"/>
<button ng-click = "uploadFile()">UPLOAD FILES</button>
```

#### Server

```
app.use(multer({
    dest: 'uploads/',
    rename: function(file2, file2) {
        return "file1"
    },
    rename: function(file2, file2) {
        return "file2"
    }

}));
```

when i'm returning  **`return file1+"file1"`** and **`return file2+"file2"`** the files are renamed as **`originalnamefile1`** and **`originalnamefile2`**.
tried a few things but unable to get it right . My nulter version is 0.1.6

Comment: You can't have multiple properties with the same name. The second `rename` will override the first. The rename-function has this signature: `function (fieldname, filename) { ... ` and every file will pass through it. So you have to do something like: `if (fieldname == "file1") return "file1";`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple `rename` func doesn't make any sense, last will always override previous ones. Take a look at sample below

```
app.use(multer({
    dest: 'uploads/',
    rename: function(fieldname, filename) {
        //check fieldname
        if(fieldname === 'file1') {
            //be aware, no file extension added here
            //if you want to add ext - use
            //return 'file1.' + filename.split('.').pop();
            return 'file1';
        } else if (fieldname === 'file2') {
            return 'file2';
        //do something when fieldname is different
        } else {
            //generate some id
            return Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
        }
    }
}));
```

Comment: @mscdex you are looking at multer 1.x, above code is for multer 0.1.x and OP says _My nulter version is 0.1.6_ So it has rename in 0.1.x